# tiny mce adding two br on soft return

Tags: tinymce

When I use soft return in tinyMCE it's adding two `<br />` tags. If you add some text on next line then it will return only one `<br />` which is right, but happens only when I use soft return with empty line.

Can any one help me why this is behaving like this.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate what you are seeing and that may be a defect in TinyMCE.  I would create an issue in the TinyMCE issue tracker:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues

Please be as detailed as possible in your explanation to make sure they can replicate the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Fromin, we can easily recreate this as just type some text on first line and end of the line just use the soft return and check tinyMCE.activeEditor().getContent(), you can see the extra br tag